# Почему в Данном Коде функция Main вместо 0 - возвращает -1073741819

Tags: c++, windows, ооп, перегрузка-операторов

```
#include "agl.h"

int main() {
    //std::cout << "Hello, world !" << std::endl;

    plane_metric::dynamic_frame<char> animation(3);

    plane_metric::plane<char> obj(10, 10, '$');
    plane_metric::plane<char> sub(10, 10, '?');

    animation[0] = obj;

    return 0;
}
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
agl.h
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
#include <iostream>

/* 2D Metric -> Functional */

namespace plane_metric
{
    template<typename Field>
    class plane
    {
    private:
        Field** field   = nullptr;          // Field Buffer
        int str         = 0;                // Strings Count
        int coll        = 0;                // Collums Count

        void clear(const Field def);        // Filling field buffer default value
    public:
        /* Constructors */
        plane();

        plane(const int str, const int coll, const Field def);

        plane(const Field** field);
        plane(const Field** field, const Field def);

        plane(const int coord_str, const int coord_coll, const plane<Field>& obj);
        plane(const int coord_str, const int coord_coll, const Field** obj);

        /* Main Funclional */
        void one_pixel(const int coord_str, const int coord_coll, const Field ch);

        void fill(Field ch);
        void fill(const int coord_str, const int coord_coll, const int str, const int coll, const Field ch);

        void insert(const int coord_str, const int coord_coll, const plane<Field>& obj);
        void insert(const int coord_str, const int coord_coll, const Field** obj);

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        void output();
        void output(const int coord_str, const int coord_coll, const int str, const int coll);

        /* Getters & Setters */
        void Set_field(const int str, const int coll, const Field def);

        void Set_str(const int str);
        void Set_coll(const int coll);

        int Get_str();
        int Get_coll();

        /* Ending */
        ~plane();

    };

    template<typename Field>
    class dynamic_frame {
    private:
        plane<Field>* frame     = nullptr;
        plane<Field>* save      = nullptr;

        int size                = 0;
        int real_size           = 0;
    public:
        /* Constructors*/
        dynamic_frame(const int size);

        /* Operators */
        plane<Field>& operator=(const plane<Field> obj);
        plane<Field>& operator[](const int index);

        /* Ending */
        ~dynamic_frame();

    };
};

/* Plane Metric -> PLANE -> Functions */

template<typename Field>
void plane_metric::plane<Field>::clear(const Field def)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < this->str; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < this->coll; j++) {
            one_pixel(i, j, def);
        }
    }
}

template<typename Field>
inline plane_metric::plane<Field>::plane(){}

template<typename Field>
plane_metric::plane<Field>::plane(const int str, const int coll, const Field def)
{
    Set_field(str, coll, def);
}

template<typename Field>
inline plane_metric::plane<Field>::plane(const Field** field)
{
    this->field = field;
}

template<typename Field>
plane_metric::plane<Field>::plane(const Field** field, const Field def) : plane(field)
{
    clear(def);
}

template<typename Field>
plane_metric::plane<Field>::plane(const int coord_str, const int coord_coll, const plane<Field>& obj)
{
    this->insert(coord_str, coord_coll, obj);
}

template<typename Field>
plane_metric::plane<Field>::plane(const int coord_str, const int coord_coll, const Field** obj)
{
    this->insert(coord_str, coord_coll, obj);
}

template<typename Field>
inline void plane_metric::plane<Field>::one_pixel(const int coord_str, const int coord_coll, const Field ch)
{
    this->field[coord_str][coord_coll] = ch;
}

template<typename Field>
void plane_metric::plane<Field>::fill(const Field ch)
{
    clear(ch);
}

template<typename Field>
void plane_metric::plane<Field>::fill(const int coord_str, const int coord_coll, const int str, const int coll, const Field ch)
{
    for (size_t i = coord_str; i < str + coord_str; i++) {
        for (size_t j = coord_coll; j < coll + coord_coll; j++) {
            one_pixel(i, j, ch);
        }
    }
}

template<typename Field>
void plane_metric::plane<Field>::insert(const int coord_str, const int coord_coll, const plane<Field>& obj)
{
    for (size_t i = coord_str; i < obj.str; i++) {
        for (size_t j = coord_coll; j < obj.coll; j++) {
            this->field[i][j] = obj.field[i][j];
        }
    }
}

template<typename Field>
void plane_metric::plane<Field>::insert(const int coord_str, const int coord_coll, const Field** obj)
{
    for (size_t i = coord_str; i < obj.str; i++) {
        for (size_t j = coord_coll; j < obj.coll; j++) {
            this->field[i][j] = obj[i][j];
        }
    }
}

template<typename Field>
void plane_metric::plane<Field>::output()
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < this->str; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < this->coll; j++) {
            std::cout << this->field[i][j];
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

template<typename Field>
void plane_metric::plane<Field>::output(const int coord_str, const int coord_coll, const int str, const int coll)
{
    for (size_t i = coord_str; i < this->str + coord_str; i++) {
        for (size_t j = coord_coll; j < this->coll = coord_coll; j++) {
            std::cout << this->field[i][j];
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

template<typename Field>
void plane_metric::plane<Field>::Set_field(const int str, const int coll, const Field def)
{
    this->str = str;
    this->coll = coll;

    this->field = new Field * [this->str];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < this->str; i++) {
        field[i] = new Field[this->coll];
    }

    clear(def);
}

template<typename Field>
inline void plane_metric::plane<Field>::Set_str(const int str)
{
    this->str = str;
}

template<typename Field>
inline void plane_metric::plane<Field>::Set_coll(const int coll)
{
    this->coll = coll;
}

template<typename Field>
inline int plane_metric::plane<Field>::Get_str()
{
    return this->str;
}

template<typename Field>
inline int plane_metric::plane<Field>::Get_coll()
{
    return this->coll;
}

template<typename Field>
inline plane_metric::plane<Field>::~plane()
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < str; i++) {
        delete[] field[i];
    }
    delete[] field;
}

/* Plane metric -> DUNAMIC_FRAME -> Functions */

template<typename Field>
inline plane_metric::dynamic_frame<Field>::dynamic_frame(const int size)
{
    this->size = size;
    this->frame = new plane<Field>[size];
}

template<typename Field>
inline plane_metric::plane<Field>& plane_metric::dynamic_frame<Field>::operator=(const plane<Field> obj)
{
    return obj.field;
}

template<typename Field>
inline plane_metric::plane<Field>& plane_metric::dynamic_frame<Field>::operator[](const int index)
{
    return this->frame[index];
}

template<typename Field>
inline plane_metric::dynamic_frame<Field>::~dynamic_frame()
{
    delete[] this->frame;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Вбиваем в калькулятор -1073741819 и переводим в хекс. Видим C0000005. А это знакомый нам "Access violation". Значит, скорее всего, кто то пишет за пределами массива или обращается к удаленной памяти.

Comment: Хм.. А что, так можно? о_О А на ideone аж в stderr выводится, что не так))

Comment: да, калькулятор можно запускать. а можно clang c `-fsanitize=...` запустить

Comment: Я просто не знал, что код возврата можно конвертировать во что-то осмысленное...

Comment: по стандарту, если я правильно помню, только от 0 до 127 "официально допустимые", все остальное - на усмотрение разработчиков. Под виндой оно так. Под линуксом, если помню, 255 возвращает в случае подобных крешей.

Answer (score 2):

Как говорит ideone, ты дважды освобождаешь одну и ту же память: https://ideone.com/07jNbv

> free(): double free detected in tcache 2

Если убрать строчку с присваиванием

```
animation[0] = obj;
```

то всё работает https://ideone.com/TJUhTu.

Наверное, ты не определил конструктор копирования, а значит копируются указатели, после чего два объекта указывают на одно и то же поле. Соответственно, при их уничтожении каждый из них пытается его освободить.

PS: А пример мог бы и упростить.